# set timer on jquery pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am opening a jquery popUp div using

```
 $("#saveDialogSingleFeature").dialog();
```

I only want the div to appear for 3 seconds then close automatically
tried this using `$("#saveDialogSingleFeature").dialog('close')}, 3000);`

but this doesnt do anything....shouldnt it close?

```
 $(function () {
            $("#saveDialogSingleFeature").dialog();
            $("#saveDialogSingleFeature").dialog('close')}, 3000);
        });
```

Comment: Your code contains a syntax error. You have one `}` after `dialog('close')` which doesn't make sense there.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(function () {

        $("#saveDialogSingleFeature").dialog();
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#saveDialogSingleFeature").dialog('close')
        }, 3000);

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('popupafteropen', '.ui-popup', function() {
 setTimeout(function () {
  $(this).popup('close');
 }, 3000);
});
```

Plz Let me know this works for you or not

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in "open" section with use of `setTimeout`:

```
$("#saveDialogSingleFeature").dialog({
    open: function() {
        var a = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            a.dialog('close');
         }, 3000);
    }
});
```